# Creating a visual tree from JSON file

Tags: python, json, tree

There is a lot of info how to create a tree inside JSON file, but is there any way to visualise dependencies from JSON file to any visual interface, picture or terminal as tree ( like on pictures ) ?

Stole this pictures from another post

[image: Tree 1]

[image: Tree 2]

There is my code to generate JSON from database ( Im generating parentID with Radom module ) :

```
    emp = []
for item in root.iter('empl'):
        name_tag = {'name': '', 'dep': '', 'Title': '', 'email': '', 'id': int(item.attrib['id'])}
        for data in item.iter('field'):
            if data.attrib['id'] == 'displayName':
                name_tag['name'] = data.text
            elif data.attrib['id'] == 'dep':
                name_tag['dep'] = data.text
            elif data.attrib['id'] == 'Title':
                name_tag['Title'] = data.text
            elif data.attrib['id'] == 'Email':
                name_tag['email'] = data.text
            elif data.attrib['id'] == 'id':
                name_tag['id'] = data.text
            else:
                continue
        emp.append(name_tag)


session_factory = sessionmaker(engine)
session = session_factory()


emp_list = [TableName(name=item['name'], department=item['dep'], Title=item['Title'], email=item['email'], id=item['id']) for item in employees]
avoid_duplicates = list(connection.execute('select * from TableName'))


for i in emp_list:
    if i.name not in [j[1] for j in avoid_duplicates]:
        session.add(i)

session.commit()

write_list = [{'id': i[0], 'name': i[1], 'dep': i[2], 'Title': i[3], 'email': i[4]} for i in list(connection.execute('select * from TableName'))]

session.close()
connection.close()


for randomID in write_list:
    randomID['parentId'] = random.randrange(0, 487, 2)

with open('data.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(write_list, file)
```

Afther this JSONs looks like :

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Name1",
    "dep": "dep",
    "Title": "title",
    "email": "email",
    "parentId": 408
},
{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Name2",
    "dep": "dep",
    "Title": "title",
    "email": "email",
    "parentId": 316
},
{
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Name3",
    "dep": "dep",
    "Title": "title",
    "email": "email",
    "parentId": 160
}
```

Is there any way how I can visualize 'id - parentID' relations to a visual tree ?

Comment: Consider using graphviz - https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/

Comment: @scotty3785 im a bit confused how to put my 'id' and 'parent id' to nodes for tree creation, I get an 'NoneType' object is not callable error, when Im trying to put random id from JSON to dot.node() arguments

Comment: Sounds like you need to post a new question with some example code. You'd create a node per object, and then use the parentId to link nodes to their parents. Your example doesn't have any objects with matching parents e.g. an object with id 160 doesn't exist but this is object 12's parent.

Comment: @scotty3785 its exist, I have 487 items, I put just 3 for example

Comment: Ok. Suggest you create all the nodes first and then go back though the list a second time to link each item to the parent i.e. the edges. As I said, perhaps add a new question since your original isn't about trouble with graphviz